# Edit application path when using AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: java, eclipse, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

With local tomcat my application url is: http://ip:port/myapp
but when deploying it to AWS Elastic Beanstalk the url becomes http://some_domain.com. I want the url to be http://some_domain.com/myapp.

How do I do that? I found something about adding some config file to .ebextensions but I wasn't sure what exactly I should do and whether it helps at all.

**UPDATE:**

I created an .ebextensions folder and put the the following files:

**server.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
    <Listener SSLEngine="on" className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener"/>
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener"/>
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener"/>
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener"/>
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener"/>
    <GlobalNamingResources>
        <Resource auth="Container" description="User database that can be updated and saved" factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory" name="UserDatabase" pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"/>
    </GlobalNamingResources>
    <Service name="Catalina">
        <Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>
        <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443"/>
        <Engine defaultHost="localhost" name="Catalina">
            <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
                <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
            </Realm>
            <Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true">
                <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"/>
                <Context docBase="EizeRest" path="/EizeRest" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:EizeRest"/>
            </Host>
        </Engine>
    </Service>
</Server>
```

**server-update.config**

```
container_commands: 
  replace-config: 
    command: cp .ebextensions/server.xml /etc/tomcat7/server.xml
```

And when deploying I'm getting the following error:

"aws Unable to detect application deployment"

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

**Another update:**

I see in the events tab of the server the following error: cannot stat '.ebextensions/server.xml': No such file or directory

Comment: How do you deploy your app? Via war or zip?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will need to take the following steps:

1. create a Tomcat server.xml file that sets `path=myapp`
2. copy this file to beanstalk during its deployment phase

Beanstalk documentation provides a relevant guide for that here:
http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/10/customize-elastic-beanstalk-using-configuration-files.html

Basically the guide says you need to copy the server.xml to beanstalk by creating the following file in your application root: `.ebextenstions/tomcat.config`:

```
container_commands: 
  replace-config: 
    command: cp .ebextensions/server.xml /etc/tomcat7/server.xml
```

don't forget to commit both the `server.xml` and the `tomcat.config` files in the .ebextensions folder.

Comment: Where do I take the server.xml from? I took the server.xml from my local tomcat and I'm getting an error when deploying: "aws Unable to detect application deployment". Please see an update in my original message

Answer (score 0):

You must place your ".ebextensions" folder at the same level as your WEB-INF folder. Doing that will remove the ".ebextensions/server.xml: No such file or directory" error.