# How to update changes on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: eclipse, amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an Elastic Beanstalk server. When first deploy my application on it everything works fine. I'm not sure how I update the environment with my code changes.
I tried to do the following:
Right click on my project --> Amazon Web Services --> Deploy to AWS Elastic Beanstalk
A window with a progress bar appeared and nothing happens, it gets stuck.
Please see screen shot below.
[image]

Is there a different way to do this?

**Update:**
after a while (maybe 15 minutes) I got the following message:
"aws Unable to detect application deployment"

Comment: did you see [this thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=89947) suggesting you need to have the environment in a healthy state?

Comment: Apparently I'm getting the error after adding .ebextensions  folder with server.xml and server-update.xml files. When removing this folder everything works fine. Please see this thread:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34494431/edit-application-path-when-using-aws-elastic-beanstalk. And I tried adding healthy state and it didn't help.